# python regex match case option

Tags: python, regex, findall, ignore-case

I would like to utilize a match case option. I have a piece of code to search a string in a list. I guess there is a more elegant way to do the same.

```
searchString = "maki"
itemList = ["Maki", "moki", "maki", "Muki", "Moki"]

resultList = []
matchCase = 0

for item in itemList:
    if matchCase:
        if re.findall(searchString, item):
            resultList.append(item)
    else:
        if re.findall(searchString, item, re.IGNORECASE):
            resultList.append(item)
```

I could use `re.findall(searchString, item, flags = 2)` because `re.IGNORECASE` basically an integer (2) but I don't know which number would mean "matchcase" option.

Comment: `[x.lower() for x in itemList]` returns the lower-cased list, you don't really need a regex for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce the case insensitive search inside the comprehension:

```
searchString = "maki"
itemList = ["Maki", "moki", "maki", "Muki", "Moki"]

resultList =[]
matchCase = 1

if matchCase:
    resultList = [x for x in itemList if x == searchString]
else:
    resultList = [x for x in itemList if x.lower() == searchString.lower()]

print resultList
```

It will print `['maki']` if `matchCase` is `1`, and `['Maki', 'maki']` if it is set to `0`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/I6sIzg)

Comment: I just realize, my original list was to simple. What if we have items in the `itemList` like `"makiMuki", "mikimaKi"`, etc.?

Comment: If you search for `makimuki` case-insensitively having `makiMuki` in your list,  it should be found. Could you please fork my IDEONE demo to showcase the issue you have now?